# Sum without use of loop in R

Tags: r, vectorization

I've a vector.

```
basket <- c(4,5,10,102,10);
```

If I've to sum, I could call

```
sum(basket)
```

If I've to use for loop to find out sum,

```
total <- 0; len <- length(basket); for(i in 1:len) {total <- total + basket[i]}
```

Is there a way I could find total, without using sum(), or using this lengthy for loop construct?

Comment: Just curious - why don't you want to use sum?

Comment: To learn if there is better/faster of doing things; Particularly learning more about vectorization as I'm used to "for/while" loops...

Comment: But sum = + ... I dont get it. Also loops are not vectorization actions. `+` for example is vectorized.

Comment: Yes. I know loops are not vectorization.. that's why I want to do away with it..

Comment: If you really want to be creative you can also do stuff like `max(cumsum(basket))` :)

Comment: Ha ha. that's really interesting :)  but it also has to be faster.. :P

Comment: Oh yeah I know... just goofin around a bit... Sundays do that :) but really `sum` is the fastest way to go with.

Comment: If you want to learn more about R, dig into profiling of code.

Comment: Thanks. Will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add <- function(x) Reduce("+", x)
add(basket)
```

or write a shorter loop:

```
s <- 0
for(a in basket) s<- s+a
```

Comment: Thanks for new function! I need to get out of this habit of looping with indexes...  :)

Comment: In using loop, assigning to "s" would return NULL. So second line should be just  "for(a in basket) s<s+a", without assigning to s again..

Answer (score 2):

sum in R is really fast. There is no need to use a for loop for such a basic operation. 
You can find a small benchmark between a C++ loop,  R loop and the R sum-function here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html (see the "Vector input, scalar output" section)

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I'm just trying to learn more about R, and particularly vectorization, loops, and different ways of applying functions. So just trying to push as much as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

There's [`sum`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sum.html), which sums the elements of a vector, and [`Reduce`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html), which applies a function to the elements of a vector such that a kind of running state is kept and modified on each call and then returned as the results.

(Unfortunately I don't program in R so I can't tell you how to use them, but these are common functions in modern languages.)